# Why does it print True? Comparing string with different length

Tags: python-3.x

```
print('AC' > 'ABC')
```

If comparing the same length of string, i am aware of ord(). But for diff length, isnt 'AC' supposed to be smaller than 'ABC' because the len() / length for "ABC" is longer?

why am i getting true output instead of false?

Comment: Which one would come first in a telephone directory? String comparison has nothing to do with length.

Comment: @Selcuk well, if following your logic, shouldnt 'UN' > 'Z' return True since 'UN' comes first in a telephone directory? but it returns False. why?

Comment: No, it's the other way around. Being "greater than" means that it comes after, i.e. `"Z" > "UN"` because `UN` comes first. Your own experiment validates that, too (`AC` comes after, so it is greater than `ABC`).

Comment: @Selcuk your comment makes sense now. just confirming, that only refers to strings that are different in lengths right?

Comment: As I said, comparison has nothing to do with lengths. Even with similar lengths you would compare the order of each letter in the alphabet. `AC` > `AB` because `A==A` and `C>B`. Also note that lowercase letters are "greater than" their capital counterparts, because of ASCII encoding (i.e. `"foo" > "FOO"`).

Comment: @Selcuk then lets say i have this dictionary as follows:
dict = {1: 'Z', 2: 'MAX', 3: 'IS', 4: 'DEF', 5: 'UN', 6: 'A'}
if i were to return max(dict.values()), what would it give me and why?

Comment: It would give you the last entry that you would find in a telephone directory, i.e. `"Z"`.

Comment: @Selcuk, nope youre wrong. It gives me 'UN'

Comment: Works as expected for me here.

Comment: @Selcuk, ah sorry, i popped out Z earlier in my code lol... thank you so much. good analogy! all clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the expression

```
print('AC' > 'ABC')
```

Is printing `True` is because of comparing `a-z` chars the compression is checking if A is greater then A and then if C is greater then B and because of that AC is greater then ABC you can check it by the sort method

```
ls = ['c', 'a', 'd', 'y', 'b']
sorted(ls) #Output ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'y']
```

the default of this method is ascending order that mains that c is greater than b.

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing the length here but the weight of the string ordered alphabetically.

If it comes after in alphabetical order, then it will be greater.

Because "AC", comes after "ABC" so it is greater,
so AC > ABC will be `true`

But if you want to compare by length so doing that :

```
print(len('AC') > len('ABC'))
```

Will, of course, output `false`.

Check this out for further example : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Python/String/How_to_compare_two_string_values_in_Python.htm

Comment: what do you mean by order?

Comment: I mean that if in alphabetical order it will comes after, then it is considered as greater, i also update my answer to be more clear